# How do STIs and STDs physically enter the body?

Tags: sex, sti, virus

Nurses and health practitioners will tell you to wear a condom to prevent contracting an STD/STI, and will supplement this with "diseases and infections can be transmitted through bodily fluids which come in contact with cuts and wounds" etc.

But how does the virus enter the body? which specific parts of the body/organs come into play? Is there a specific part of the penis/vagina where the skin allows the virus to permeate or does it go through the urethra Where does the virus originate from and how does it reach its end destination?

Comment: Welcome to MedicalSciences.SE! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require prior research information when asking questions. *See [this list of helpful resources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google?

Comment: Related: https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/q/16500

Comment: I don’t want to get into the broader side of this, but the skin under the prepuse of an uncircumcised penis is relatively more permeable, and inside the anus is more permeable. It’s tender. Easier to get tiny cuts.

Comment: Of course there are different stds which really require an analysis of each.